# 3 divs next to each other not working properly

Tags: html, css

I got a webpage I want to change a bit in code. I have to the  left circle menu's, in the middle text and to the right pictures. I want to make 3 seperated divs / columns.
You can see here what I mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/5NWm4E868nXYyixd2SLv?p=preview

Basically I want to make 3 long divs where u can e.g. just copy paste all the pictures in with some space between (vertically) and all the text in the other div.

So the page has to look the same.

Right now I have this (just the relevant portion): https://plnkr.co/edit/8re5W6mz73pnU40WaXP8?p=preview

So it doesn't really look like the orignal page. My question is what am I doing wrong ? And when I want to add another circle menu of picture for example, it
will appear next to it instead of below it. And then the whole page is messed up. How to fix this ?

```css
#pageMiddle {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#midleft {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
}

#midmid {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}

#midright {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.imageleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 00% 10% 00% 00%;
}

.circle {
  border: solid 2px #73B7DB;
  background: #73B7DB;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 440%;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.imageright {
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 174px
}
```

```html
<div id="pageMiddle">
  <div id="midleft">
    <a class="imageleft circle" id="how">
      <font color="white">Wie</font>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div id="midmid">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</div>

  <div id="midright"><img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you have to wrap whole div like this inside `#pageWrapper`

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="pageMiddle">
      <div id="midleft"><a class="imageleft circle" id="how"><font color="white">Wie</font></a></div>
      <div id="midmid">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</div>
      <div id="midright"><img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageMiddle">
      <div id="midleft"><a class="imageleft circle" id="how"><font color="white">Wie</font></a></div>
      <div id="midmid">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</div>
      <div id="midright"><img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and some change is css

```
#pageWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  /*max-width:1200px;*/
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#pageMiddle {
  width: 100%;
  margin:10px 0;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hareesh, your answer is looking pretty good. Maybe I haven't formulated what I want good enough. So I want 3 long divs. I want this so that I can put the pictures everywhere I want, like put 1 big picture that is the same size of 2 paragraphs. But now I can put 1 picture next to a paragraph and I dont have much freedom. 
Here is an example about the 3 long divs I want: http://jsfiddle.net/8njq1505/

Comment: still not clear what you intent. do you have any reference how it should look?

Comment: https://ibb.co/jDF6hF Have a look at this, this is the kind of format I would like to go for. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to look at the difference in your code. The code you want to achieve does not have separate divs for the components rather it separates them with margins and restricts the image size and circle. Then floats floats them. The text just fills the remaining space available. The different rows are separated by margin in flexible terms (i.e. %).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% what you're looking for but as far as I can see you could simplify this hugely by utilizing flex-boxes. Though there are many ways of going about this, flex boxes seem to be the cleanest and easiest (to me).

Place the 3 divs inside a flex-container and give each inner div a % width.
(borders are just to help show div areas)

```
<article class="container">
<div class="leftCol">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Lol_circle.png" />
</div>     
<div class="centCol">
<p> Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
</p>
</div>     
<div class="rightCol">
<img src="http://ursispaltenstein.ch/blog/images/uploads_img/random_natural_acts.jpg" />
</div>
</article>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
display:flex;
}
.centCol {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 50%;
}
leftCol, rightCol {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 25%;
}
.leftCol img, .rightCol img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps. Here's the link in-case you want to toy with it.. https://codepen.io/11PH/pen/NvNZoe?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for what you want to achieve. It uses bootstrap framework and also is responsive. You can check the code out in the following example.
It uses only 4 CSS classes and built in bootstrap responsive `col-*-*` classes to adjust the layout.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/OjNebO

Hope this helps and adds good knowledge.